# Why doesn't this gradient work in Safari Browser?

Tags: html, css, safari

Following Gradient does not works in Safari.

```
.navbar-right li:first-of-type{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(-57deg, #fff 250px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100px) repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add this to your code

```
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(-57deg,  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 250px,#fff 100px);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(-57deg, #fff 250px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100px) repeat scroll 0 0;
```

need to use `background-image` `-webkit-linear-gradient` for it to work on safari

well i've tested in safari 5.1.7 for windows ( very old version ) and it's working . see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/vm7uej69/1/)

so it must work for you too

Comment: Nope.. it's not working. I have used :first-child instead of :first-of-type. but its not working in Safari..http://stackoverflow.com/users/6441124/mihai-t

Comment: Yes. I Have used the code in my css. and it working fine in Mozilla and chrome ..but not working in safari Browser.

Comment: Here is My Code :-

`navbar-right li:first-of-type
 {
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(-57deg,  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 250px,#fff 100px);
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(-57deg, #fff 250px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100px) repeat scroll 0 0; 
}`

Comment: share also your html ( edit your question ) it might be something else going on there

Comment: `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-img">
<li>
<a class="hvr-wobble-bottom" href="">
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/call.png" height="25" width="25">
<span class="pick-up"> Dial a Pick Up...0123456789</span></a>
</li>
</ul>`

Comment: well i've tested in safari 5.1.7 for windows ( very old version ) and it's working . see here https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/vm7uej69/1/

Comment: yes. Its Working Fine Now. I have just change the value of 

`background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(-57deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 250px,#fff 100px) TO

background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(-47deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 38px,#fff 20px).`

Thanks for helping..